# Use English locale for keystrokes with modifiers

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, locale

In my Linux system, I use English, Russian and Ukrainian locales. Because the latter two are non-latin (cyrillic), my hotkeys don't work with these locales.

Is it possible to always interpret keys as English, when they are pressed with modifier keys?

I am running Arch Linux with i3.

Comment: In principle that's possible, but you'd have to write your own keyboard layouts resp. rewrite the existing ones (either with `xmodmap`, or with `xkbd`).